# Setting decimal places in coordinate-grid in QGIS Print Layout

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer, grids-graticules, decimal-points

I have a grid with coordinates on my map in the Print Layout of QGIS. But in one map I have decimal coordinates that look like this:

```
12.500°E / 52.300°N
```

And sometimes they look like this:

```
12°E / 52°N
```

So where do I set the number of decimal places for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the precision: "Map Grid Properties" in the "Draw Coordinates" section at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's it!